# How to fix WebView app giving "App Keeps Stopping" error after installing?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-webview

I have a web view app that works perfectly fine on most android phones, but while testing, some said that the app even won't open for the first time after installation.

It keeps on showing the error as below :
["Keeps Stopping"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOwT1.jpg)

And in some mobile devices, it says `"Runtime Exception"` and crashes without even opening.

This was a debug APK, so in an attempt of trying to fix it, I even generated a signed APK. Still no luck.

Here is my whole Code:

**Activity Main.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webviewid"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx;">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_roundffd"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme_xxxxxx"
       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Mainactivity.java**

```
package com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webviewid);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.some.com/");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }
        });
    }

// On double back press stuff starts --------------------------------------------------
    private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // .... other stuff in my onResume ....
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }
}
}
```

Please note that the app works completely fine, It installs and opens with no issues, but when it comes to some phones, I am getting this "Keeps Stopping" error.

As per some blogs, I even tried uninstalling updates from the Android Web View setting, yet still no use.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting on your console during this crashes

Comment: I'm directly installing and checking the app in mobile. In android studio, there is no error while building.

Answer (score 0):

can you remove the 'smallestscreensize' in android:configChanges in manifest file and let us know.

Comment: Hi, removed it, still not opening in few devices. App getting installed, but not opening. In some phones, it says, `Run Time Exception`

Comment: I have another webview app, it works perfectly fine in all devices, only that it was build on java 1.8 graddle. the moment i upgrade it to java 11 , it stops working in few devices

Comment: Do you know how to get crash errors in android studio

Comment: @Harry we can try a workaround. use try catch blocks in every methods of every activity, in catch block, use toast or alert dialog to get the error when using. You dont know where this error is occuring and also this is not on all devices, so try this you may get exception. For each catch block add a flag so you know at which event exception is occuring